# shamsi Calendar in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

I want create shamsi calendar and add calendar type in sharepoint.
Please tell me how can I do it?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this goal using multiple approaches.

- You can write your own Shamis Calendar Webpart and then you can add Webpart to any webpart zone.
- You can create ASP.NET control and utilize it as per details given [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985556/add-asp-net-control-to-sharepoint-web-part)